# Dot product dimension issue with theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

This is my first question on stackoverflow. Hopes it fits the expected format.

I'm simply trying to make a function that computes a dot product between a matrix and a vector:

```
A = T.matrix()
B = T.vector()
C = T.dot(A,B)

a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = numpy.array([[1],[0]])

f = function([A,B],C)
```

When I ask the product to numpy, I have no issue. `numpy.dot(a,b)` returns my expected `array([[1],[3]])`

But when I ask `f(a,b)` to Theano, I've got this error: `TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "<stdin>:1"  at index 1(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 1, got 2 with shape (2, 1).')`

My understanding was that Theano typing expected my `Y` declared as vector to necessarily be in 1D.
I've therefore tried with `b = numpy.array([1,0])` instead. Maybe theano will understand that it has to be a column to be able to compute ? 
Now the result I get is `array([[ 2.,  2.],[ 4.,  4.]])`, which is even more of a mystery to me.

I've find similar topics around but none with an explanation I could grasp. I realize it must appear obvious for many of you, but I'd appreciate a hand !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type the following

```
b = numpy.array([1,0])
```

it internally creates is a column matrix of shape Rx1. That's how vectors are represented generally.

Now when you type in,

```
b = numpy.array([[1],[0]])
```

And then pass it to function f, it throws an error because it is expecting a Vector and you are passing a Matrix as the second parameter. Change B to type matrix, and it works fine.

So, either do this :-

```
A = T.matrix() 
B = T.matrix()
C = T.dot(A,B)

a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = numpy.array([[1], [0]])

f = function([A,B],C)

print f(a,b)
```

Or you can treat B as a vector itself, and pass a vector which would be

```
A = T.matrix()
B = T.vector()
C = T.dot(A,B)

a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = numpy.array([1,0])

f = function([A,B],C)

print f(a,b)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both these solutions already, and they both return array([[2,2],[4,4]]), which I don't understand. But maybe I just misunderstood what T.dot() does in the first place...

Comment: Both of the above pieces of code return [1 3] and [[1] [3]] respectively. In the first case, it is a vector that is returned of dimension 2x1. In the second case it is a matrix that is returned of dimension 2x1. You can check your result by trying `numpy.dot(a,b)`

Comment: I ran again both codes, and yes, I get my [1,3] vector.
I can't figure out what I messed up yersteday when I had [[2,2],[4,4]] as a result. Must have done something wrong in the cmd console.
Thanks anyway !

Comment: Glad I could help!